# RuntimeError: can't create new thread at interpreter shutdown while it works perfectly fine on another computer

Tags: python, networking, runtime-error, editor, python-multithreading

I have a python program that I run in VSCode but at one point I'm getting this RuntimeError: can't create new thread at interpreter shutdown and I'm not even closing anything, I don't understand. And by the way the same programm works perfectly fine on my friend computer (we have the exact same one)

Code (sorry it's a bit long but I can't make it shorter, I've already excluded everything that wasn't essential):

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
import threading
import time

class Main:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        
        # Variables to check if the progress bar is running (not crucial for the current issue)
        self.is_progress_bar_running = False
        self.is_change = False
        self.state = None
        self.client_loaded = False
        # Launching everything in parallel
        thread_client_list = threading.Thread(target=self.client_list) 
        thread_client_list.start()
        thread_get_sites = threading.Thread(target=self.get_sites)
        thread_get_sites.start()
        tkinter_start = threading.Thread(target=self.show_gui)
        tkinter_start.start()

    def client_list(self):
        """Find clients
        """

        time.sleep(3)
        
        self.client_loaded = True
        return

    def get_sites(self):
        """Find sites
        """

        time.sleep(3)

        return

    def start_progress_bar(self, direction):
        """Starts the loading bar until everything is loaded

        Args:
            direction (bool): True if the bar is moving to the right, False if the bar is moving to the left
        """
        if not self.is_progress_bar_running:
            self.is_progress_bar_running = True
            # If self.client_loaded
            if not isinstance(self.client_loading, ttk.Progressbar):
                self.state = None
                self.is_change = False
                
                self.client_loading_label["text"] = "Loading clients in progress..."
                self.client_loading.destroy()
                self.client_loading = ttk.Progressbar(self.general_info_frame, orient="horizontal", length=100, mode="indeterminate", takefocus=True, maximum=100, value=0)
                self.client_loading.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=20,pady=20)
                self.client_loaded = False
                # Restart loading clients and sites
                self.thread_client_list = threading.Thread(target=self.client_list) 
                self.thread_client_list.start()
                self.thread_get_sites = threading.Thread(target=self.get_sites)
                self.thread_get_sites.start()
            
            # If direction is True, move forward
            if direction:
                self.client_loading['value'] += 25
                # Change direction when reaching the end
                if self.client_loading['value'] + 25 > 100:
                    direction = False
                # Destroy the loading bar when everything is loaded
                if self.client_loaded:
                    if self.state == 3:
                        self.client_loading_label["text"] = "Error: no internet connection\nReload?"
                        self.client_loading.destroy()
                        self.client_loading = tkinter.Button(self.general_info_frame, text="Reload clients", command= lambda: self.start_progress_bar(True))
                        self.client_loading.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=20,pady=20)
                        self.is_progress_bar_running = False
                    else:
                        self.client_loading_label["text"] = "Clients loaded!\nReload?"
                        self.client_loading.destroy()
                        self.client_loading = tkinter.Button(self.general_info_frame, text="Reload clients", command= lambda: self.start_progress_bar(True))
                        self.client_loading.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=20,pady=20)
                        self.is_progress_bar_running = False
                # Otherwise, start again
                else:
                    self.is_progress_bar_running = False
                    self.window.after(400, lambda: self.start_progress_bar(direction))
            # Otherwise, move backward
            else:
                self.client_loading['value'] -= 25
                # Change direction when reaching the end
                if self.client_loading['value'] - 25 < 0:
                    direction = True
                # Destroy the loading bar when everything is loaded
                if self.client_loaded:
                    self.client_loading_label["text"] = "Clients loaded!\nReload?"
                    self.client_loading.destroy()
                    self.client_loading = tkinter.Button(self.general_info_frame, text="Reload clients", command= lambda: self.start_progress_bar(True))
                    self.client_loading.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=20,pady=20)
                    self.is_progress_bar_running = False
                # Otherwise, start again
                else:
                    self.is_progress_bar_running = False
                    self.window.after(400, lambda: self.start_progress_bar(direction))

    def show_gui(self):
        """Function that displays the entire interface
        """
        self.window = tkinter.Tk()
        self.window.title("Synchroteam Task Creation Form")

        self.frame = tkinter.Frame(self.window)
        self.frame.pack()

        # User information
        self.general_info_frame = tkinter.LabelFrame(self.frame, text="General Information")
        self.general_info_frame.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=20,pady=20)

        # Client loading bar
        self.client_loading_label = tkinter.Label(self.general_info_frame, text="Loading clients in progress...")
        self.client_loading_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.client_loading = ttk.Progressbar(self.general_info_frame, orient="horizontal", length=100, mode="indeterminate", takefocus=True, maximum=100, value=0)
        self.client_loading.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=20,pady=20)

        for widget in self.general_info_frame.winfo_children():
            widget.grid_configure(padx=10, pady=5)

        if not self.client_loaded:
            # Start the loading bar until everything is loaded
            self.window.after(400, lambda: self.start_progress_bar(True))

        # Start the loop
        self.window.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = Main()
```

And here is the error I get :

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1962, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\Utilisateur\Documents\Batitech\API\test.py", line 97, in <lambda>
    self.client_loading = tkinter.Button(self.general_info_frame, text="Reload clients", command= lambda: self.start_progress_bar(True))
                                                                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\Utilisateur\Documents\Batitech\API\test.py", line 59, in start_progress_bar
    self.thread_client_list.start()
  File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\threading.py", line 992, in start
    _start_new_thread(self._bootstrap, ())
RuntimeError: can't create new thread at interpreter shutdown
```

The error is not happening when I'm starting the program. The clients and the sites are loading fine at launch, but when I try to reload the client while clicking on the button self.client_chargement when it has been changed to a button after the client has been loaded at launch, the error pops up.
And I repeat that this exact same programm works perfectly fine on my friend computer.

Thank you in advance if you take the time to read everything and answer me !

Comment: it's a big bunch of code to read, have you tried to isolate the error by removing part of the code?

Comment: @cards it should be better now, I deleted everything that wasn't important =)

Answer (score 0):

I changed my python version in VSCode (from 3.12) to 3.11 and now it's working I don't have the error anymore, I don't really know why but the problem came from python 3.12

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).